# CSP header in firefox iframes working on whole page with dynamic content

Tags: html, firefox, iframe, content-security-policy

It seems to me that Content-Security-Policy meta tag in iframe content prevents loading dynamic images in my main page. This issue is Firefox-only (56 version). Here is the example:

Test.html

```
</html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="button" id="btn" value="GO" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
      src = 'https://www.google.ru/logos/doodles/2017/fridtjof-nansens-156th-birthday-5694774550986752-s.png',
      img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = src;
      document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
    </script>
    <img src="https://www.google.ru/logos/doodles/2017/fridtjof-nansens-156th-birthday-5694774550986752-s.png"/>
    <iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>

  </body>
</html>
```

iframe.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' *.jquery.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self' data:;"></meta>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px;">
    <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

After clicking on "GO" button in any other browsers, you can see images being added to page, but in Firefox nothing happens and an console error shows up, saying

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at
>   https://www.google.ru/logos/doodles/2017/fridtjof-nansens-156th-birthday-5694774550986752-s.png
>   (“img-src file:// data:”).

Is it a bug? Is there any workaround? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Firefox Configuration by hitting url **"about:config"** and search for security.csp and make the values to "false" i.e.. disable the flags .

Here is screen shot :

[image]

Note - this is just a workaround , as it will make your system less secure .

Better Solution is check

1. what is your csp header and change header to appropriate policy .

   Here is the link for understanding strict csp and policies :

https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/index.html